# Running etherpad as a service on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, services

I am setting up etherpad-lite on my raspberry pi ubuntu 14.04 server. I got stuck trying to make etherpad-lite run as a service, following [these instructions](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-deploy-Etherpad-Lite-as-a-service) (I've also checked several others but that hasn't helped).

After starting the service with

```
service etherpad-lite start
```

i get a discouraging response:

```
start-stop-daemon: unable to open pidfile '/var/run/etherpad-lite.pid' for writing (Permission denied)
```

I tried to change the permissions for the file, give writing privileges to etherpad (the user running etherpad), but that changed nothing.

```
sudo chown etherpad:etherpad /var/run/etherpad-lite.pid
sudo chmod 754 (also tried 777, just to see) /var/run/etherpad-lite.pid
```

I tried running the service etherpad-lite with sudo, and as user 'etherpad'. Both of these options seem to work at first,

```
Starting Etherpad Lite... 
done
```

but upon checking in browser or by running service etherpad-lite status, I lean that it's still not working:

```
[FAIL] etherpad-lite is not running ... failed!
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

*I already asked this question at stackoverflow, raspberrypi.stackexchange and askubuntu. I got no substantial replies.

Comment: [Cross posting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/595495/running-etherpad-as-a-service-on-raspberry-pi-fail) is against the [rules of this site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)